# Character sent for SQL query is echo'ing a special character?

Tags: php, sql, character

So I have a database filled with jobs with a jobId, customer name, invoice and purchase number. For each of these, I have set up 4 individual searches for each of those that will return entries containing the text searched.
Depending on which value is being searched for, the variable entered in the url will vary. I used the php `$_GET` statement to grab whichever value it is and populate an SQL query that filters the data with that value.

A sample of the code for the table is below:

```
if (isset($_GET['customerName'])) {
    $customer = $_GET['customerName'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE `customerName` LIKE \"%".$customer."%\"");
    $number = $result->num_rows;
    echo $number." results found.";
    echo "<table class='auto details1' id='customer' data-type='table' data-other='groupBy=jobID' data-filter='`jobs`.`customerName` LIKE \"%".$customer."%\"  ' data-columns='jobID,customerName,invoiceID,purchaseOrder,notes,jobStatus,pallets'></table>";}
```

This table is linked to a `getTable.php` page which takes the filters and other values set for the table and outputs the relevant data.
However, the problem I'm having when searching for a customer name is that I may search for a name starting with `"ec"`, which returns `"%ec"` as the value in the query, which is `"ì"`.

I've tried escaping the *%* character, but the problem is that I need it to be present in the SQL query so that I can return values before the value searched for.

Sorry if this is confusing, I'm so confused as to what to do that I can't explain it.